# How can I exicute my previous code( how to go back in the window.)

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code I'am trying to execute my two different code in same window or it seems like it is executing in same window.
When I'm clicking on "next_button" is execute the function "next_screen". Here we have again a button by which I'm trying to execute my previous (main_screen) code but it's not working.
If my logic of trying to execute two codes in same screen is wrong. Then please let me know and then how can I execute two or more files code in same root(screen or window).

```
import tkinter as md

def next_screen():
    frame.destroy()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    
    def main_screen():
        next_frame.destroy()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.geometry("200x200")
                
    next_frame = md.Frame(root)
    next_frame.pack()
    label = md.Label(next_frame, text = "Click bellow button to go to main window", pady = 20)
    label.pack()

    button = md.Button(next_frame, text = "Clikc Me", font = "verdana 15", command = main_screen)
    button.pack()



root = md.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
frame = md.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
label = md.Label(frame, text ="Main window", pady = 20)
label.pack()

next_button = md.Button(frame, text ="Go Forward", font = "verdana 15", command = next_screen)
next_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With this code I'm able to go in forward direction but cannot come back. Maybe it will use loop to execute.

Comment: No.. I don't know how to use multithreading. Will you please help?

Comment: @RyanFu how would that help? all of `tkinter` should be run in one thread only anyways

Answer (score 0):

It becomes much easier if you use a class for something like this. Here is a quick example I made:

```
import tkinter as md


class Screens:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.main_screen()

    def main_screen(self):
        if self.frame is not None:
            self.frame.destroy()
        frame = md.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()
        label = md.Label(frame, text="Main window", pady=20)
        label.pack()

        next_button = md.Button(frame, text="Go Forward", font="verdana 15", command=self.next_screen)
        next_button.pack()
        self.frame = frame

    def next_screen(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        next_frame = md.Frame(root)
        next_frame.pack()
        label = md.Label(next_frame, text="Click bellow button to go to main window", pady=20)
        label.pack()

        button = md.Button(next_frame, text="Clikc Me", font="verdana 15", command=self.main_screen)
        button.pack()
        self.frame = next_frame


root = md.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
screen = Screens()

root.mainloop()
```

Make sure to modify it to suit your needs.